# Advance AutoFilter to exclude certain values

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I want to filter a large list of names in a Sheet in excel.  In another sheet I have contained a list of names that I want to filter out and exclude from the larger list. How would I use the advanced filter to do this? I have tried this below but it is not seeming to work. My big list is in `K2:K5000` and my criteria is in `H2:H3` (The criteria will grow but I kept the list small for testing). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Filter()
    Sheet5.Range("K2:K5000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H2:H3"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of a criteria you would want applied?

Comment: Interesting question in my opinion. Deserves an UV. Btw, I posted an answer to illustrate how you work with `Advance Filter` but the most favorable answer would be @user3964075. It covers all bases :-)

Answer (score 5):

To **exclude** the values in `H2:H3` from `K2:K5000` using advanced filter you can use following approach:

- Make sure cell `K1` is not empty (enter any header)
- Find 2 unused cells (e.g. `I1:I2`)
- Leave `I1`blank
- Enter the following formula in `I2`

  ```
   =ISNA(MATCH(K2,$H$2:$H$3,0))
  ```
- Use the following code to exclude rows

  ```
   Sheet5.Range("K1:K5000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
       CriteriaRange:= Sheets("Sheet3").Range ("I1:I2"), Unique:=False
  ```

Comment: Definitely plus one! :-) This will handle multiple values to filter out!

Comment: Great Answer! I automated building the Formula via VBA in my post you helped solve! Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65986101/5079799

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure off the top of my head how you would use advanced filter to exclude, but [you can use formulas in your advanced filter](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html) (near the bottom). You can, however, just use a dictionary to store values you want to exclude, then exclude (hide rows, or autofilter on the ones not found in your exclusion list)

```
Sub Filter()
Dim i as integer
Dim str as string
Dim dict As Object

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    For i = 2 To 3
        str = CStr(.Range("H" & i).Value)
        If Not dict.exists(str) Then
            dict.Add str, vbNullString
        End If
    Next i
End With

With Sheet5
    For i = 2 To 5000
        str = CStr(.Range("K" & i).Value)
        If Len(str) > 0 And dict.exists(str) Then
            .Range("K" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Elseif
            'alternatively, you can add those that aren't found
            'to an array for autofilter
        End if
    Next i
End With

'If building autofilter array, apply filter here.

End Sub
```

Using AutoFilter:

Use an array of strings as criteria to filter on with the "Operator:=xlFilterValues" argument of AutoFilter. Build your array however you want, I chose to do it by building a string with a for loop and splitting (quick to write and test, but not ideal for a number of reasons).

Note: AutoFilter is applied to the headers, not data.

```
With Sheet5
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("K1").AutoFilter _
      Field:=1, _
      Criteria1:=arr, _
      Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this exclude the values that I have in H1:H3?

Comment: I originally misunderstood your question, I've edited my answer appropriately. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand first how to use the Advance filter.
There is a good tutorial you can find [HERE](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html).

Now based on that, let us make an example. Suppose you have below data:

[image]

Now, let us say you want to filter out **Data1** and **Data2**.
According, to the link you can use a formula as criteria but:

> Note: always place a formula in a new column. Do not use a column label or use a column label that is not in your data set. Create a relative reference to the first cell in the column (B6). The formula must evaluate to TRUE or FALSE.

So in our case, our relative reference is `A11`(the first cell or item in the field you want filtered).
 Now we make a formula in `B2` since we cannot use `A2`, it is a Column Label. 
Enter the formula: `=A11<>"Data1"`.

[image]

Above took care of **Data1** but we need to filter out **Data2** as well.
So we make another formula in `C2` which is: `=A11<>"Data2"`

[image]

Once properly set up, you can now apply `Advance Filter` manually or programmatically. A code similar to yours is found below:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A10:A20").AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, .Range("A1:C2")
End With
```

And Hola! We have successfully filtered out **Data1** and **Data2**.

**Result:**

[image]

It took me a while to get a hang of it as well but thanks to that link above, I manage to pull it of. 
 I have learned something new as well today :-). HTH.

**Additional:**

I see that you have your criteria on another Sheet so you have to just use that in your formula.
 So if in our example you have **Data1** and **Data2** in `H2:H3` in Sheet2, your formula in `B2` and `C2` is: `=A11<>Sheet2!H2` and `=A11<>Sheet2!H3` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really even need VBA for this... to achieve the same result:

1. Put the values into a separate spreadsheet, in the first column.
2. Create 2 new columns next to the data you want to filter in your original spreadsheet
3. In the first column next to your data to be filtered, use

   `=VLOOKUP(A2, [nameOfOtherSpreadSheet.xlsx/xlsm/xls/etc]sheetName!$A:$A,1, FALSE)`

Where A2 is the value you're searching for, field 2 is the reference of the range in which you want to search for this value, 1 is the index of the column in which you're searching, and FALSE tells `VLOOKUP` to only return exact matches.

4. In the second column next to the data you want to filter, use

   `=IFERROR(G2, FALSE)`

Where G2 is the reference of the function that might return an error, and FALSE is the value you want to return if that function throws an error.

5. Filter the second column next to the data you want to filter for FALSEs

This should return the original data set without the values you wanted to exclude.

Record a macro to do this it's one step instead of 5 for future uses.