# VBA AdvancedFilter Filter and copy unique cells without blank (empty) cells

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am new in VBA and stackoverflow.com too

I am using this code to remove duplicate cells in column where I copy unique cells to the next column, but code count empty non-blank cells for unique data. Ok, but I dont need to copy empty cell in the new column.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("BA4:BA59").AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("BB4"), _
UNIQUE:=True
```

I searched and found

```
SkipBlanks:=True
```

, but when I add it code goes to the hell ;)

Please tell me how to skip blanks and "" cels
Column with duplicates contain IF formulas IF(A4="Print";"Text for printing";"")&IF(A4="Cut";"Text for cutting";"")
Possible results in cells

1. Text for printing
2. Text for printing
3. ""
4. Text for cutting
5. Text for cutting

So I need in new column only

1. Text for printing
2. Text for cutting

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

this is an interpretation of: [Advance AutoFilter to exclude certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504517/advance-autofilter-to-exclude-certain-values)

Find two empty cells, I chose BA1:BA2 and put a this formula in the second of the two:

```
=LEN(BA5)>0
```

And left the first Empty.

[image]

Then using the following code:

```
Range("BA4:BA9").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
    "BA1:BA2"), CopyToRange:=Range("BB4"), Unique:=True
```

I was able to do what you want:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It works. Thank for the link. It helps.

Comment: @Servlet if this worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.