# Excel VBA: Advanced Filtering Blanks Not Working

Tags: excel, vba, filter, advanced-filter

I have a userform that uses a checkbox to filter out blanks for a certain column. The range to be filtered is Sheet 1 A1:C10, and the criteria range is Sheet 2 A1:C2.

If checked: Don't filter Column C
If unchecked: Filter out blanks on Column C

I have looked around and found that the operator to filter blanks on an advanced filter is "=". Therefore, when I process the filter when I press a button on the userform, I set Sheet 2 C2 to "="

```
If Checkbox1.Value Then
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = ""
Else
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = "="
End If

Sheets(1).Range("A1:C10").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Sheets(2).Range("A1:C2"), Unique:=False
```

When I process this, all entries disappear, even blanks. The same is true if I use:

```
Else
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = "<>"
```

This should show non-blanks, but it hides all rows.

Here's the kicker; to troubleshoot, I recorded a macro of me auto-filtering blanks, and it gave me this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$2").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
```

So, it seems that filtering "=" is correct, but it just doesn't want to work with me.

---

**Side note:** just for kicks, I thought that the criteria cell needed to show ="", which means that the formula would read ="=""""", which means that the VBA would read:

```
Else
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = "=""="""""""""""
```

This also does not work.

---

**Edit:** @Scott, I have the following four lines. None of which seem to work. The linked page shows an example to remove blanks, not exclusively show them. Therefore I tried =0 in addition to >0.

```
Else
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = "=LEN(Sheet1!C2)=0"

Else
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = "=""=LEN(Sheet1!C2)=0"""

Else
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = "=LEN(Sheet1!C2)>0"

Else
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = "=""=LEN(Sheet1!C2)>0"""
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537165/vba-advancedfilter-filter-and-copy-unique-cells-without-blank-empty-cells/39538548#39538548

Comment: basically the formula you want is `=LEN(Sheet1!C2)>0` where `C2` is the first cell in your data set that you want to test for non blanks.

Comment: I have reopened.  I will do some test.  but try: `sheets(2).Range("C2").Formula = "=LEN(Sheet1!C2)=0"`

Comment: This is still a duplicate, we just missed a step.  But since I did not see that right off I went ahead an gave the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay we missed a step.

> ***C1 on sheet2 needs to be empty.***

The formula will take care of the filter part.

Then the code is:

```
If Checkbox1.Value Then
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = ""
Else
    Sheets(2).Range("C2").Formula = "=LEN(Sheet1!C2)=0"
End If

Sheets(1).Range("A1:C10").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Sheets(2).Range("A1:C2"), Unique:=False
```

Comment: Voodoo I say! It worked :) Thanks!  -  For anyone else that stumbles on this, if you're using a criteria range that is smaller than the filter range, the empty header needs to be on the same column offset. For example, if you filter A1:Z3000 and you want to apply this to column Q, your empty header in the criteria range needs to be on the 17th column.