# Advanced filter error

Tags: vba, excel, advanced-filter

I am trying to create a unique list but the first value in the list is a blank and that seems to be causing me a problem.  When I use a basic advanced filter it essentially just names the range 'Extract' and copies the formatting.  So F2 equals `Extract' as below, 
[image]

I have tried many approaches using the criteria range but nothing seems to works.  Ideally I want this to be VBA code but the manual Advanced Filter is not working.  To clarify I am searching like this,

[image]

I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537165/vba-advancedfilter-filter-and-copy-unique-cells-without-blank-empty-cells), it's just not working for me.  Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Is it the 'Copy into new location' option that is messing this up?  Ideally I need it to be unique fields but I seem to be getting the same results, with or without the unique fields only box ticked.

Eventually I want this to be the code but, when I run the below in VBA I get a Run-Time error. 
`Range("E2:E5").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
    "h1:h2"), CopyToRange:=Range("F2"), Unique:=True`

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<>` for the criteria to exclude blanks.

[image]

btw, your List Range should be E1:E5 and H1 should be *Offset values*. Advanced Filters **require** a header.

Comment: Hi, @Jeeped, originally (playing around with other options) I was getting two blanks before my unique list but now with your recommendation I get one.  I do not understand why.  I have edited my post to show you what I mean.  Just so you know, I clear all info in the existing cells and delete any past named ranges that may have been created.  There are no formulas either.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce your error (blanks included) is to put a space (or some invisible character like a CHAR(10) line feed in E2 or E3. Select E2:E3 and use Home, Editing, Clear, Clear All and run Advanced Filter again manually.

Comment: Yeap, that was it.  Thank  you.