# Filter by maximum value in a field/column using Advanced Filter in Excel

Tags: excel, max, advanced-filter

I need to filter a field by maximum value, but I need to use advanced filtering in order to show the result in another sheet.
I tried using *max*, *>* etc alone but didn't work.

The field in question is numeric and I need to show the row that contains the maximum value in that column.
I know how to filter text and how to use <, >, <=, >=, and and or conditions, but I can't figure out how to do things like max, min etc.

I can't use a Pivot Table since I need to filter by another column by *contains text* and I'm using wildcards, and I already searched inside all pivot table options and could not find anything to filter rows by text, so that's why I'm using advanced filtering.
I'm using Excep 2002.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537165/vba-advancedfilter-filter-and-copy-unique-cells-without-blank-empty-cells/39538548#39538548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key is to create a formula that returns TRUE/FALSE.

In G2 I put:

```
=A2=MAX($A$2:$A$15)
```

Then in the advanced search I add my List Range: `A1:B15`

Then I include `G1` and `G2` in my Criteria Range.  `G1` must be blank.

I decided to copy to `D1:E1`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was not the result I was looking for thouth.
I just wanted to know between the results of those rows that contained a text, which of them has the max value.
Anyways, I found the way to know it.
Thanks anyways.
What I wanted was:

{=Max(If(Iserror(find("text";range))=false;rangewithnumbers))}