# Using Advanced Filter to filter out rows where Column H is blank AND Column G is 0

Tags: excel, advanced-filter

So it seems I am having trouble setting up the criteria I would use to filter out rows where Column H is blank AND Column G is 0. Both these conditions need to be met for that row so it can be filtered out.

[In the image, we are getting all entries where the Signoff Date is not blank and where Signoff Duration is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjwJh.png)

I want to return all data except where Column G is blank AND Column H is 0.

Comment: please show what you have tried.  It will help us help you.

Comment: Provided image and explanation.

Comment: see here on how to use a formula in the criteria for advanced filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110719/filter-by-maximum-value-in-a-field-column-using-advanced-filter-in-excel