# Is there VBA code to exclude items from filter based on another list

Tags: excel, vba, list, filter

I have a massive list of data that I need to filter down. I need to exclude certain account numbers from the original list. The list of account numbers changes on a regular basis. The list of excluded accounts will be part of a specific range, in my example called "Exmpt_Cust".

I was able to grab another piece of code that filtered the list based on my defined range, but it only showed those accounts, rather than removing the accounts. Basically, it was the inverse of what I wanted to do. Below is the code.

```
Sub Below_Min_()
'
' Below_Min_Macro
'
'
    Sheets("Order").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Dim ar As Variant

    ar = Range("Exmpt_Cust")
    ar = Application.Transpose(ar)
    ar = Split(Join(ar, ","), ",")

    Range("G6", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter 1, ar, 
xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

I just need help to figure out how to invert this. Currently, it only shows the accounts on "Exmpt_Cust" and I need it to remove those accounts and only show all "others".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421061/vba-autofilter-exclude-multiple-criteria

Comment: Or after filering the "unwanted" values, grab the visible cells in the column using SpecialCells, unhide everything, then hide the cells you grabbed.