# How can i use filter by multiple data (list) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use filter by multiple data in Excel VBA.
at first time, 
I used 'for' and 'find' method, but it's too slow for processing.

In case of Python, Use the 'Pandas modules'and dataframe, Like below sample
filter = dataframe['headername"].isin([Listdata1, Listdata2, Listdata3..])

but I couldn't find similar method in VBA.

Here is My background data[1](https://t1.daumcdn.net/cfile/tistory/99CADB345C2C201418):

[image: excel capture]

Comment: I've removed the excel-vba tag. The description fo that tag clearly says (in ALL CAPS) that the tag is pending removal and should not be used, and explains what should be used instead. Please read the description of tags before using them to make sure they're appropriate for your question. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite - I've have been wondering why the access-vba, word-vba, powerpoint-vba tag descriptions never received that 'disclaimer'?

Comment: @user10852207: Don't know. You might ask at [meta] to see if anyone does, though. There's also a link to [meta] in the description of the excel-vba tag after the notice that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: Nice dodge @kenwhite

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MultiSelectFilter()

    Dim arr As Variant

    ' Range containing values to be shown
    arr = Range("C1:C3")

    ' Range to be filtered
    Range("A1").AutoFilter
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(arr), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is that i wanted, i have a one more question, Can i filter reversed selection(invert) by modifying operator?

Comment: @HeartAimDJ - nope.  Excluding multiple criteria is much more complex - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504517/advance-autofilter-to-exclude-certain-values?rq=1

Comment: That's too bad, Thank you